# Display record from two tables via common field (not foreign key)

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

**t1**

```
id|pid
------
 1|1
 2|1
 3|3
 4|3
 5|2
 6|5
```

**t2**

```
id|pid|message
--------------
 1|5  |message 1
 2|5  |message 2
 3|3  |message xxx
 4|2  |message yyy
 5|3  |message zzz
```

I want to display something like this:

```
t1.id|t2.id|message
-------------------
    3|    3|message xxx
    3|    5|message zzz
    4|    3|message xxx
    4|    5|message zzz
    5|    4|message yyy
    6|    1|message 1
    6|    2|message 2
```

Is it posssible using one mysql query?

Comment: It's just an ordinary join. You can join on any columns, they don't have to be foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

You have to simply join these tables on cloumns which have same values if there is no foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

mysql query:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.id, t2.message
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp